# SSL error when using Keycloak as a federated identity provider with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: ssl, keycloak, keystore, sslhandshakeexception, wso2-identity-server

I'm running a Keycloak instance in standalone mode. I have configure the Keycloak as an OIDC federated IdP in the WSO2 IS and configured the WSO2 IS as a client in the Keycloak. I also have an application running which is connected to WSO2 IS and uses Keycloak for federated authentication.
I can log into the application without any issues, but when I try to logout from the application, logout happens in the Keycloak but there's the following error in the Keycloak console,

`[org.keycloak.services] (default task-17) KC-SERVICES0057: Logout for client 'WSO2-IS' failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I tried creating a keystore, `standalone/configuration/application.keystore` and importing the certificate of the WSO2 IS to it and importing the certificate of the Keycloak to WSO2 IS keystore. But it didn't work. (Note that `application.keystore` wasn't in the `standalone/configuration/` location even after the sever was started.)

I also followed this [guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#outgoing-http-requests) to setup a keystore but nothing seems to work.

Is there something I'm missing in this setup ?

Comment: Some intermediate CA certs may be missing. It's common problem of Let's Encrypt users. They don't import/configure intermediate certs, so proper verification path can be verified.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. After your comment I  checked the certs in the keystore and it seems that the WSO2 IS certificate was not properly imported. Now the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue after checking the certs in the truststore of the Keycloak.

Reason: cert of the WSO2 IS was not properly imported and truststore was not properly configured.